# install linux-headers-4.15.0-32

Tags: dependencies

My Ubuntu Software program is not working correctly.:

When trying to update the software, it always repeats
the package linux-headers-4.15.-32 needs to installed.

everytime i want to re install or update I receive this message

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.15.0.32.54) but 4.15.0.29.51 is to be installed

what to do?

Comment: Open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install -f` and paste the output in your question

Comment: No. Just `sudo apt-get install -f`. It is used to install unmet dependencies. Most of the times it works.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: @ George Udosen I receive a similar answer  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.15.0-32 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: not yet resolved.I downloaded and installed, restarted PC but I still receive this message               jocaers@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for jocaers: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.15.0-32 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: I am not really sure but I think you need to look at sources.list file. Please please paste the output of `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` in question body or https://pastebin.ubuntu.com and post the link.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic-hwe-16.04` to the question.